# Do I need to protect my Android app from being copied?

Tags: android, security

Do I need to protect my Android app (downloaded from Google Play Store) from being copied? I'm following links to documents which say conflicting things.

If I search "app encryption" using Google Play Developer Console help, it shows me the ['Google Play Licensing Service'](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?hl=en-GB) web page which ends:

> Please note that starting with JellyBean release of Android OS, all
>   apps, paid as well as free, are encrypted by default and, therefore,
>   do not require any additional protection against unauthorised copying
>   such as Google Licensing Server.

['Filters on Google Play'](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)  says:

> Google Play no longer supports the Copy Protection feature in the
>   Developer Console ...

and provides a link to '[Replacement for Copy Protection](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html#CopyProtection)'. This links to '[Setting Up for Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html)', which links to '[Adding Licensing to Your App](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)', which links to '[Market Licensing Support FAQ](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?visit_id=1-636102113342195047-760807730&rd=1)', which displays the '[Google Play Licensing Service](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?visit_id=1-636102111458329000-760807730&rd=1)' web page (with the above text which indicates that post-Jellybean apps are encrypted). So, unless I am misunderstanding it, this appears to contradict itself.

Judging by dates of other posts on this topic, I'm guessing that I do have to do my own app protection using the Google Market Licensing LVL (Licence Verification Library). However, there are signs that this is not the current best solution (e.g., Market Licensing sample app appears out-of-date, few recent forum posts on using it, no udacity.com classes I could find on using it). So I thought it would help to get a definitive answer first.

Comment: It's time to add the links/URL. You got the reputation :)

Comment: Thanks! I added the links.

Comment: Several years later and this is the first result on Google. Is the information in the question and answers still actual today?

Answer (score 3):

First it is not possible to protect your code 100%. But you can make the job of the hacker tough enough. There are some techniques for protecting your code [protect android app](http://mobilenext.net/protect-android-app-app-pirates/). I recommend to you to see the [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) tool.

> ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names. The resulting applications and libraries are smaller, faster, and a bit better hardened against reverse engineering.

Comment: That helps - tx, especially [protect android app](http://mobilenext.net/protect-android-app-app-pirates/). I agree about proguard which I am using.

I would be very interested to know if post-Jellybean app encryption feature is still active. That is, can anyone get my APK file and redistribute it as their own app? [Filters On Google Play](https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) seems to say encryption is no longer used. [Google Play Licensing Service](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?hl=en-GB) says it is used. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: My understanding is that after Jellybean the app encryption feature is inactive. Now you have to use Google Play Licensing Service to protect your app from redistribution.

Comment: Could you let me know where you get that information from? I ask because it seems to contradict the [Google Play Licensing Service](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/186113?hl=en-GB) web page (which says post-Jellybean apps are encrypted). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Having considered feedback to this post (thanks), I believe the answer is "no", I do not need to protect my app from being copied as the questionable benefit would not justify the effort (rationale explained below). However, this answer is based on the app I am currently developing and will not apply to all.

The app does not depend on a server component, and consequently will function in isolation. That is, if someone gets a pirate copy of it, they will be able to run it. However, the app will have a low price. So if someone makes a copy and starts selling it illegally, they would need to sell a lot of them to make any money and justify their effort and risk being taken. They may also choose to give away a pirate copy of the app, but I am guessing that most users of such a pirate version would not have paid for it in the first place.

If I integrate the Google Market Licensing LVL, this would make it difficult to pirate the app. However, with sufficient effort, it could be reverse engineered to source code (even with me using Proguard), the LVL functionality could be eliminated, and the app rebuilt. Also, LVL integration is a significant effort (for me, at least), it risks introducing bugs into the app, and I am unconvinced whether it is a good solution (Market Licensing sample app appears out-of-date, few recent forum posts on using it, ...). Consequently, I don't think the effort and risk are worth the benefit.

If the app had a high selling price, my answer would likely be different, and I would consider other options. For example Google Market Licensing LVL could be integrated, but this would not eliminate the piracy risk completely, unless Android did provide secure app encryption. App encryption seems to me a big challenge (given, for example, that it needs to be decrypted at some point to run it), which may explain why the post-Jellybean app encryption was removed (if it was removed). I could also move functionality to be server-side - this seems the most secure strategy to me, although it would be expensive to develop and would require the server-side to be managed and maintained going forward.

It's likely there are aspects of this that I have not considered. Please comment if you disagree with my answer, or have other thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If your APP was providing a kind of service, online game(a Server required), you can just protect your service by some register/authorization rule.

Or, if your APP was a tool, standalone game, it's actually hard to protect. There is some website provide a service which allow user direct download APK file from GooglePlay, and without any purchase......Anyone can install those APK by just allow install APP from non-GooglePlay source. In this case, you do need some way to protect your APP from being copied.

Comment: That's interesting about the website which provides app downloads without purchase. Thanks for the feedback.